# Jquery issue: why isnt my code be affected by the jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm learning Jquery at the moment and I cant seem to workout my mistake in this basic code. The goal is to show a dropdown menu when the user hovers their mouse over "Menu item 2". Please can somebody help me see my mistake. Here is a link to the code if it doesn't display properly below: http://www.door9.co.uk/nav.html

```
<style>
     ul          {list-style : none; padding : 0; width: 100%; }
     ul li       {display: inline;}
     li          {display : inline; margin-right : 20px; }
     li ul       {display : none; }
     li:hover ul {display : block; width: 145px; position: relative; left: 160px; }
</style>

<body> 
 <div>
   <ul>
    <li>Main list item one</li>
    <li>Main list item two &darr;
       <ul>
            <li>Sub list item one</li>
            <li>Sub list item two</li>
            <li>Sub list item three</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Main list item three</li>
    <li>Main list item four</li>
   </ul><!-- UL close -->
 </div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1 jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').has('ul').hover(function(){
        $('li ul').slideToggle(function(){
          $('li ul').slideToggle();
        });
    });
  });
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Works for me in chrome (at least it animnates the menu)

Comment: why use the .has('ul')? unless you have some li in another element such as a 'nav' element, you dont need this extra method

Comment: How do I get the sub menu to toggle under the menu item 2. It seems to bounce...

Comment: @atmd Im trying to get the code to say "slideToggle" only on the menu item ('li') with a unordered list inside of it. Have I wrote it wrong?

Comment: @AndrewJohn No you have written it right. But that's only one way of doing it. A cleaner way is probably to have a class on the top level menu and select that, or use the container (in your case `div > ul > li`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
li:hover ul {display : block; width: 145px; position: relative; left: 160px; }
```

in your CSS may be interfering.

Could the code below be what you are looking for?

```
<html>
<head>  

  <style>
    ul    { list-style: none; padding: 0; width: 100%; }
    ul li { display: inline; }
    li    { display: inline; margin-right: 20px; }
    li ul { display: none; }
  </style>

</head>
<body>

  <ul>
    <li>Main list item one</li>
    <li>Main list item two &darr; 
      <ul>
        <li>Sub list item one</li>
        <li>Sub list item two</li>
        <li>Sub list item three</li>
      </ul>
    <li>Main list item three</li>
    <li>Main list item four</li>
  </ul>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   

  <script>     
    $('li').has('ul').hover(function() {
      $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
    }); 
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want to style the `li>ul` you may perhaps write the style into the `li ul` selector (not `li:hover ul`), and then use `hide()` in jQuery when the document loads. This is also good practice for when your viewer may have JavaScript turned off or unavailable (since in the present case the `li>ul` never shows if JavaScript is off).

Also, the selectors `li` and `ul li` seem redundant, but I digress...

Answer (score 1):

1) The [jQuery hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method takes two arguments, the mouseenter event handler, and the mouseleave event handler. (You only have one)

2) You seem to be selecting all submenus inside the handler. Most likely you only want the one inside the item you are hovering.

This is probably closer to what you are trying to achieve:

```
$("li").has("ul").hover(function () {
    $(this).find("ul").slideDown();
}, function () {
    $(this).find("ul").slideUp();
});
```